# Sharing dataframe across multiple instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-multithreading

In the below code snippet, I want to share DataFrame (g_df) across all the instances of 'Producer' class however structure of the data frame will be known only when first instance of 'Producer' is created (inside 'producer.process_event' call). Right now, g_df is accessible to a single instance only.

In a scenario when DataFrame schema is known only at the time of creation, how can I make global DataFrame variable that can be used by all instances of 'Producer' or other calling modules ?

```
import pandas as pd

class producer:
#g_df = None
#g_number_of_columns = None

def __init__(self):
    pass

def process_event(self):
    g_dynamic_column_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    g_number_of_columns = 3
    self.g_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=g_dynamic_column_list)
    new_record = list()
    for i in range(0, g_number_of_columns):
        new_record.append(i)
    pos = self.g_df.shape[0]
    self.g_df.loc[pos] = new_record

def disp(self):
    print(self.g_df)

prod1 = producer()
prod2 = producer()
prod1.process_event()
prod1.disp()
#Below call throws exception since g_df is not part of prod2 instance
#prod2.disp()
```

Comment: why did you tag this with multithreading?

Comment: sorry, actually I am using this in my multithreading application where producer will be running in background thread and several callers (consumers) will be using producer dataframe. For simplicity, I kept only necessary code block to bring attention on my problem.